# Verificar a existência de um arquivo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso verificar a existência de uma imagem vindo em uma das posições de um JSON recebido via AJAX. Será que deu para entender?

Existe alguma função equivalente ao **file_exists()** do PHP em Javascript ou jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://www.example.com/verificafotos.json',
  success: function(dados) {
   $.each(dados, function(index,value){
    value['titulo'];
    value['imagem'];

    if( SE O ARQUIVO EXISTIR (value['imagem'])) {
      $('img').src(value['imagem']);
    } else {
      $('img').src('http://www.example.com/imagemalternativa.jpg');
    }

   });
  }
});
```

Comment: Vc quer saber se algum valor possui algo com a extensão de imagem, tipo .png, .jpg etc, ou uma tag <img>?

Comment: Eu importo os dados de um DB com a informação da imagem (fototeste.jpg) e a pasta onde as fotos se encontram. Mas nem sempre a imagem existe na pasta.
Ao montar a estrutura, vindo de um JSON, não exibe a imagem no sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Com Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //arquiv não existe
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //arquivo existe
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar se a imagem existe pela URL criando um objeto `new Image()` e usando eventos como `onload` (a imagem foi carregada) e `onerror` (a imagem não foi carregada).

O `each` ficaria assim:

```
$.each(dados, function(index,value){
   var tit = value['titulo'],
       img = value['imagem'],
       imgs = new Image();

   imgs.src = img;

   imgs.onload = function(caminho){
      $('img').attr('src', caminho.path[0].src);
   }

   imgs.onerror = function(caminho){
      $('img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/imagemalternativa.jpg');
   }
});
```